# Make one button switch stages of an RGB diode

Tags: arduino

I want to be able to start off the program with nothing on, then when I push the button once, it should switch to red, then if you push it another time it should switch to green, and push it again and it should go to blue. After all that it should turn off when you push the button again, then it just loops.

Here's what I've been working with but it seems to fail.
When you push the button the first time it always goes to red, if you push it again, it does nothing. If you keep spamming the button it switches randomly through all the colors but never turns off.

```cpp
void loop() {
  int toRed = digitalRead(button);
  if (toRed == HIGH){
    switchtoRed();
    delay(250); // Give you time to take your finger off the button.
    int toGreen = digitalRead(button);
    if (toGreen == HIGH) {
      switchtoGreen();
      delay(250);
      int toBlue = digitalRead(button);
      if (toBlue == HIGH) {
        switchtoBlue();
        delay(250);
        int state = digitalRead(button);
        if (state == HIGH) {
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *it seems to fail* is not a useful problem description. In what way does it *fail* specifically?

Comment: Sorry for the bad description, hope the edit helps describe it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this with using a state machine design pattern approach:

```
int nextState = 0;

void loop(){
    while(1){
       if(digitalRead(button) == HIGH){
          switch(nextState){
              case 0: // Red Button
                  switchToRed();
              break;
              case 1: // Green Button
                  switchToGreen();
              break;
              case 2: // Blue Button
                  switchToBlue();
              break; 
              case 3: // Switch off
                  switchOff();
              break;
           }
           nextState = (nextState + 1) % 4;                         
           delay(250);
       }
       // or you can delay here
    }
}
```

And if you don't want to continue after case 3; you can break the loop using a `return` statement in case 3.

Comment: Brilliant, you forgot to do nextState++; after switchToX but this totally works!

Comment: Nope I put it outside the switch statement to run after them all.

Comment: I see that but then the program won't work without the nextState++ in each case and the nextState = (nextState + 1) % 4; below switch.

Comment: Its the same thing if you write the increment statement in each case of the switch statement, or outside the switch statement. it will run after each case in both ways.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the logic in your code is flawed. It is acting as if the `digitalRead` function is waiting until you press the button. Instead what is actually happening is the `loop` function is being called repeatedly and you're only ever really testing the outermost button test or if you spam the button, you might be lucky enough to get it to cycle through each of the colours.

Instead what you want is to just test the button and if has been pressed, increment a variable to indicate what light should be on. Something like:

```
int pressed = 0;
int state = 0;

void loop()
  {
  if(digitalRead(button)==HIGH)     
    {
    if(pressed==0)
      {
      pressed=1; 
      switch(state)
        {
      case 0:
        switchToRed();
        state++;
      break; 
      case 1:
        switchToGreen();
        state++;
      break; 
      case 2:
        switchToBlue();
        state++;
      break; 
      case 3:
        switchToOff();
        state=0;
      break;
        }
      }
    }
  else
    {
    pressed=0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, you're right about my logic, sorry I'm new to C.
Although your code works it for some reason does not instantly switch from RED>GREEN>BLUE it kind of fades to the colors with other colors in between like this: RED>YELLOW>GREEN>CYAN>BLUE and then fades out slowly when turning off.

Comment: Haha I just needed the delay, now it works fine. Thanks!